# Why is Power BI creating null values? How can I prevent Power BI to add null values below my data?

Tags: filter, null, powerbi, powerquery

I have an excel file which I regularly update in Power BI.

I added an additional line, which did not cause any issues to my operations, however, Power BI also added three "null" lines afterwards.

I do not understand why.

I thus created a table, because I thought that I would prevent this.

But I still have "null" rows appended to my lines.

The only remedy that I found is to filter rows on a column (Lapin) which as no null (and which should never in future), in the following way:

```
 #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([Lapin] = "Snip"))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

This is a really bad solution however, and I wish to address the root issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On importing from Excel, you can get dummy rows that are due to formatting, hidden formulas, rows that are holding over something in the cell reference in the background. Its not just Power BI, this happens on importing into SQL Server tables, Pandas, and on exporting the Excel to csv etc. The best option is to us the remove rows function in the Power Query

[image]

Select Remove Rows > Remove Blank Rows

Comment: Hi, but if I have columns with empty rows (and which should be empty) while others adjacent columns are not empty, is this also suppressing these? And thus suppressing rows with valuable information? I made the tests, and only bottom rows were suppressed, while remaining null rows were still "embedded" in columns. But I wonder why and it it just happened by chance.

Comment: It should remove the blank rows, but if there is something in the meta data it may not work, and you may have to add another level of filtering. In Excel select the rows then delete them. see if that does it. It can be a right pain with these ghost rows

Comment: Ha!!! Ghost rows is really a great way to put it! I am going to try to further experiment, and/or if you want to add some model of the data to illustrate what was going on. I would really love to get to the bottom of it. I was really confused by the fact that I had three ghosts rows added after the last rows of my excel file, and also by the fact that the number of column I was adding in PBI was continuing, not just for rows with values, but for these three "null" rows as well.